# Determine directional sound of sound stream

Tags: audio, direction

I am born with Single-Sided Death which, in short, means that you're death on one of your ears. Only being able to hear on one ear, makes you lose the ability to hear direction and distance of sound.

I have wondered whether it is possible to determine direction of a sound given a stereo stream of sound. For simplification, just for two channels (left and right) and with the assumption that there does not exist background noise.

What would be a good initial strategy to cope with this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ability to determine the direction of a sound mainly depends on time differences between the two ears. In real life, all sounds come from different direction. As the sounds events are mixed in only two channels, I can be pretty hard to retrieve the direction of each source. If there is few sources in your stream, or if the sounds come mainly from the same direction, you could try to calculate the directions. For this you could first identify some precise events, like attacks in the signal, and find them in the two channels (they should be close). Then, compute their time differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a interesting problem.
Also since this is a hypothetical scenario, the solution/ idea given below is also probable and will depend upon lots of factors.

Considering we have a stereo audio , using [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/API.markdown) we can split that into two mono  channels using:

> AudioSegment(…).split_to_mono()
>   Splits a stereo AudioSegment into two, one for each channel (Left/Right). Returns a list with the new AudioSegment objects with the left channel at index 0 and the right channel at index 1.

Then we can figure out which channel is loudest using

> AudioSegment(…).split_to_mono()
>   Splits a stereo AudioSegment into two, one for each channel (Left/Right). Returns a list with the new AudioSegment objects with the left channel at index 0 and the right channel at index 1.

Then we measure loudness in each channel using:

> AudioSegment(…).rms
>   A measure of loudness. Used to compute dBFS, which is what you should use in most cases. Loudness is logarithmic (rms is not), which makes dB a much more natural scale.

So for test, I used a  stereo music wave file and split to two mono channels and checked its loudness to see which channel is loudest.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sound = AudioSegment.from_file("audio.wav")
split_sound = sound.split_to_mono()

left_loudness = split_sound[0].rms
right_loudness = split_sound[1].rms
```

**Output**

```
>>> left_loudness
7030
>>> right_loudness
6993
>>>
```

Comment: This seems like a possible solution. Is it possible to extend this to 5 og 7 channels? @Anil_M

Comment: If you have a multichannel audio it may be possible. But remember, sound bounces off  in enclosed space, and difference is too fast to measure just by measuring RMS. You will need to check timing as well (which is beyond this library). You may want to post this question in signal processing area of SO: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ and do up-vote if this answer helps you in any way.